# JavaScript image.onload generates infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, recursion

I've a situation where I need to work on a user-provided image with two different functions.

1. Get user input
2. Process the image and put it back processed

note: code is incomplete and shortened for brevity. Please don't point out the irrelevant.

### 1. Get user input

```
var fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.onload = function(e){

    image        = new Image();
    image.onload = function(){

          //BEGIN OF RELEVANT SECTION
          processOnCanvasAndBack(image, myCallbackToProceed);

    };

    image.src       = e.target.result;
};

fReader.readAsDataURL(src);
```

### 2. Process the image and put it back processed

```
function processOnCanvasAndBack(image) {
    var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
    canvas.draw(image);
    canvas.doSomeStuffLikeRotatingAndColorBalance();

   //BEGIN OF RELEVANT SECTION
   image.onload = function() {
      myCallbackToProceed();
   };

   image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

## Problem

The `image.onload` from **1.** calls the function as expected but when I call the second `image.src` from **2** the first `image.onload` gets called again, which in turns calls **2** again and.... booooom, infinite loop (console spits `too many recursions`)

I tried to reset the first call with `image.onload = function(){};` in various points, but it doesn't fix the issue (no more recursion, but the functions just stop being called). Right now I'm out of ideas :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating two image objects. One for the source image, and a second for the transformed / target image. You avoid mutating existing state and causing infinite loops by repeatedly setting the `.src` of the same image object in the onload events. Avoid mutating state whenever possible. I would also suggest using the `var` keyword to define the variables locally instead of in the global scope.

```
var fReader = new FileReader();
fReader.onload = function(e){

    var sourceImage = new Image();
    var targetImage = new Image();

    sourceImage.onload = function() {
        //BEGIN OF RELEVANT SECTION
        processOnCanvasAndBack(sourceImage, targetImage, myCallbackToProceed);
    }

    sourceImage.src = e.target.result;
};
fReader.readAsDataURL(src);
```

---

```
function processOnCanvasAndBack(sourceImage, targetImage, callback) {
    var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
    canvas.draw(sourceImage);
    canvas.doSomeStuffLikeRotatingAndColorBalance();

   // BEGIN OF RELEVANT SECTION
   targetImage.onload = function() {
      callback();
   };

   targetImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
}
```